# How to put scrolling content in my blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the code parts of my posts not to be wrapped but rather scrolled horizontally. Any simple method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code in a div and then set white-space to nowrap. Finally set the overflow property to scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/GJSXM/

```
div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works exactly as I wanted. You know, I googled before and overflow-x alone was not enough the white-space has completed the trick.

Comment: Hey mrtsherman the result I found when I browse with IE6 is not good. It hides the content overflowed and no horizontal bar. Any suggestion please

Comment: @nuux - it should work in IE6. You should post your html/css into a new SO question and see what comes up. Do you really need to support IE6? Check your server logs and website at end of this comment to see whether your demographics indicate IE6 use. MS has chosen to no-prompt upgrade all IE6 users to IE8/9 depending on OS by mid-2012. They are already moving forward in Brazil. If you can avoid supporting IE I would! http://gs.statcounter.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Try something like this](http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-horizontal-scrollbars/) for more contained content like code bits.

Comment: what is this link about. It says my computer is compromised ?